# Static Method Java confusion

Tags: java, methods, static

Room Class:

```
public abstract class Room {
    public abstract int cost();
    public static Room mostExpensive = null;
    public static int highestCost = 0;
    public static Room mostExpensive() {
        return mostExpensive;
    }
}
```

Lab Class:

```
public class Lab extends Room{
    public final int LAB_CHAIR_PRICE = 50;
    int labChairs;
    int computers;
    private final int COMPUTER_COST = 1000;

     public Lab(int labChairs, int computers) {
        this.labChairs = labChairs;
        this.computers = computers;
            if (this.cost() > highestCost) {
                mostExpensive = this;
                highestCost = this.cost();
            }        
        }
     public int cost() {
        return ((LAB_CHAIR_PRICE * labChairs) + (COMPUTER_COST * computers));
    }
}
```

LectureHall Class:

```
public class LectureHall extends Room {
    private final int LECTURE_CHAIR_PRICE = 100;
    int lectureChairs;
    boolean isData;
    private final int DATA_PROJECTOR_COST = 5000;
    int dataProjector;
    public LectureHall(int lectureChairs, boolean isData) {
        this.lectureChairs = lectureChairs;
        if (this.isData = isData) {
            this.dataProjector = 1;
            if (this.cost() > highestCost) {
                mostExpensive = this;
                highestCost = this.cost();
            }        
        }
    }
    public int cost(){
        return ((LECTURE_CHAIR_PRICE * lectureChairs) + (DATA_PROJECTOR_COST * dataProjector));
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // An array of rooms for a proposed new building
        Room rooms[] = new Room[4];
        // small lecture hall with a data projector
        rooms[0] = new LectureHall(40, true);
        // large lecture hall seating 500, with no data projector
        rooms[1] = new LectureHall(500, false);
        // lab with seats for 50 and a computer for every two
        rooms[2] = new Lab(50,25);
        // smaller lab with seats for 10 and a computer for each
        rooms[3] = new Lab(10,10);

        int totalCost = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("room " + i + " costs $" + rooms[i].cost());
            totalCost += rooms[i].cost();
        }
        System.out.println("total cost: $" + totalCost);
        Room r = Room.mostExpensive(); // the most expensive room created
        // by the program
        System.out.println("the most expensive room costs $" + r.cost());
    }
}
```

So i'm having a little trouble with the mostExpensive method(). Its a static  method and I declared it in the room class, but its used by the other methods. Its supposed to find the most expensive Room. However, it doesn't find the most expensive one, and it tells me that 27500 is the most expensive (which is not). Also I had a question about the Room class. In the constructor i set mostExpensive = this. Does that work? I'm a little confused as to how all of this works, and how I can do it correctly.

Comment: You've posted your class called `Lab` twice/`Room` is missing

Comment: And Room is missing.

Comment: You're using the name `mostExpensive` both as a variable and as a method name...

Answer (score 0):

In this constructor, the "mostExpensive" is only modified if there is a projector.

```
public LectureHall(int lectureChairs, boolean isData){
    this.lectureChairs = lectureChairs;
    if (this.isData = isData){
        this.dataProjector = 1;
        if (this.cost() > highestCost){
            mostExpensive = this;
            highestCost = this.cost();
        }        
    }
}
```

Fix:

```
public LectureHall(int lectureChairs, boolean isData){
    this.lectureChairs = lectureChairs;
    if (this.isData = isData){
        this.dataProjector = 1;
    }
    if (this.cost() > highestCost){
        mostExpensive = this;
        highestCost = this.cost();
    }        
}
```

But one should not compute overall state in the constructor of a single object. This is poor design. Keep track of Rooms in some class - either Room or something new, e.g Building. Then compute the "most expensive" from whatever you have in Room. Imagine: what happens if a projector is removed? Or added in another existing Lecture Room? The possibilities of making errors are overwhelming.